# APScheduler two errors before function is executed

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using the APScheduler library to run one of my functions. However, I always get two errors before the actual function is executed, but it always properly executes on the third attempt. Why is it always missing its target run twice?

> Errors:
>
> ```
> Press Ctrl+Break to exit
> Pending jobs:
> process_new_tracking_data (trigger: interval[0:05:00], pending)
> Run time of job "process_new_tracking_data (trigger: interval[0:05:00], next run at: 2017-08-09 13:54:57 EDT)" was missed by 0:00:03.760132
> Run time of job "process_new_tracking_data (trigger: interval[0:05:00], next run at: 2017-08-09 13:59:57 EDT)" was missed by 0:00:02.039508
> completed! # print statement at the end of process_new_tracking_data`
> ```

The event_handler file:

```
def main_func():
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_executor('processpool')
    scheduler.add_job(case2_newconfig.process_new_tracking_data, 'interval', minutes=5, max_instances=1)
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))
    scheduler.print_jobs()
    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass`
```

The main file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    process = Popen(event_handler.main_func())`
```

Comment: Would you please post the code for your job? I don't see how else anybody could figure out why it's broken. Also, posting the errors you're seeing would probably help too.

Comment: Why do you use `Popen(...`?